# Big Query (Standard Sql) - month & Year dateformat

Tags: sql, looker-studio, google-bigquery

Ive Been trying to create a column that specifies a year and month (doing so by extracting the year and month from a timestamp column, and then concatenating them together). 
is it possible for that column to be a "date" type? 
The reason Im asking is to show the different values as dates (on Google Data Studio) and not as numbers. 
Ideally, it would look something like this: 
"May, 2018"
instead of "2018-05", which is my output.

thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a type of `Date` datatype that would include only Month and Year. But, you could just construct a column that assigns the first day of whatever month/year it is. That way you area at least aggregating everything to the same day data point. Then, it is just a matter of formatting how that date is displayed.

Comment: You should store the most precise information whenever you can. If today you need a certain format, to can fetch the data and transform the output. If tomorrow you need another date format, all you need to do is change/add another transformation. There's no need for a column with information that is easily calculated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you even need to create a new column here, you can just use the [`FORMAT_DATETIME`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_datetime) function:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT_DATETIME("%B, %Y", DATETIME "2018-05-09 15:30:00")
FROM yourTable;
```

This should print `May, 2018`.

Comment: I think OP is using Data Studio, so they need a DATE/TIMESTAMP type in order for Data Studio to pick it up as such.

Comment: @GrahamPolley The OP stated `doing so by extracting the year and month from a timestamp column`.  Do you interpret this to mean that there _isn't_ already a timestamp column?  If not, then it's bad design, but even in this case, we could still convert text to a date, then back to text again.

Comment: Not 100% sure. I read this: _"is it possible for that column to be a "date" type? The reason Im asking is to show the different values as dates (on Google Data Studio) "_ as OP needing a date type column to use for viz in Data Studio.

Comment: @GrahamPolley Requiring the format of `full month name, year` is a presentation thing as I read it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks a lot! its exactly what I needed.

Comment: @GrahamPolley Its actually a presentation thing, as Tim mentioned. The reason I phrased it like that is that at first, I only wanted to show months, and did so by extracting month from a date column. my output was a number, but data studio displayed it using the month's name. I wanted to do the same thing here, but I dont need to anymore, because my output right now is already in the format I wanted to show.

Comment: Mystery solved so! :) Glad you got it answered so quickly.

Comment: It really was fast, Thanks guys!